# Recognize conics from the standard equation

Tags: linear-algebra, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

Suppose $Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2+Dx+Ey+k=0$ is a conic in the Euclidean plane. How do I recognize what is it? 
In my book they have proved the determinant test that if $B^2-4AC$ is $>0$ if hyperbola, $=0$ if parabola and $<0$ if it is an ellipse.

But my confusion is that they do not include pair of straight lines and the circle(though it is a special case of the ellipse).

Comment: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Conic_Sections/Identifying_Conics and http://staff.argyll.epsb.ca/jreed/math30p/conics/general.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

Let $p=B^2-4AC$.

If $p\lt 0$, ellipse, circle, point or no curve.

If $p=0$, parabola, 2 parallel lines, 1 line or no curve.

If $p\gt 0$, hyperbola or 2 intersecting lines.

more information [here with figures](http://math2.org/math/algebra/conics.htm).

Answer (score 2):

$1. $ if it is a circle $$A=C$$ and $B=0$

$2.$ if it is a pair of straight line
$$B^2-4AC\ge 0$$ and $$ACK+\frac{BDE}{4}-\frac{AE^2}{4}-\frac{CD^2}{4}-\frac{KB^2}{4}=0$$